# An HTML5 chart based on the second dataset is erroring

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

An *HTML5 chart* based on the second dataset is throwing error. The chart type is stacked column chart.  Basing two charts on the same dataset works and gives exactly the same chart (as expected).

Subsequently pointing one of the charts to the second dataset gives an error:

`Error displaying report page. See the console for details.`

But there are no details in the console.

The sub dataset in the chart has been set and the connection expression has been set to ***Use Connection Expression***.

I am using *iReport 5.1.0*

Any help will be appreciated.

---

More details from today's debugging: Choosing PDF preview dumps the following error to the output:

```
Compiling to file... H:\QED\Design Specs\JasperReports5\New Reports\report6.jasper
Compilation running time: 1,170! 
    Filling report...
    Locale: English (United States)
    Time zone: Default
Setting up the file resolver...  
Report fill running time: 249! (pages generated: 3) 
    Exporting PDF (using iText) to file... H:\QED\Design Specs\JasperReports5\New Reports\report6.pdf!
Error exporting print... org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1 The attribute "y" of the element <text> is invalid 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1 The attribute "y" of the element <text> is invalid 
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartPdfHandler.exportElement(ChartPdfHandler.java:45)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportGenericElement(JRPdfExporter.java:2750)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:868)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:820)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:697)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:419)
    at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:1174)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Caused by: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1 The attribute "y" of the element <text> is invalid
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.getLocation(SVGTextElementBridge.java:253)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGTextElementBridge.java:209)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:213)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:219)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.ensureSvg(BatikRenderer.java:224)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.ensureSvg(BatikRenderer.java:239)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getDimension(BatikRenderer.java:157)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1436)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartPdfHandler.exportElement(ChartPdfHandler.java:43)
... 8 more  
Export running time: 1,233! 
Executing: rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL "H:\QED\Design Specs\JasperReports5\New Reports\report6.pdf"
```